# Fetch API ¿Cómo obtener datos dentro de una URL?

Tags: javascript, html, api, fetch

Me encuentro aprendiendo el tema de las API, y me encontré con el siguiente problema:
Estoy usando la API de pokemón https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon , y dentro del objeto **result** hay una **URL** y dentro de la **URL** está el dato que necesito (*para ser exacto la imagen del pokemón*). ¿Cómo puedo lograr usar la imagen de cada pokemón si quiero hacer cards con toda la primera lista de la api? 
Aquí va mi código HTML (No todo):

> Trabajé utilizando la etiqueta template.

```
    <template class="templateCard">

        <div class="card shadow col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 m-5">
            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/1.svg"
                class="card-img rounded-circle" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="text-center"> Nombre estático </h1>
            </div>
        </div>

    </template>
```

Aquí va mi código JScript:

> La parte comentada indica un intento fallido de obtener la imagen)

```
const card = document.querySelector('#padre');
const template = document.querySelector('.templateCard').content;


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    fetchData();
});

const fetchData = async () => {
    const api = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";
    try {
        const res = await fetch(api);
        const data = await res.json();
        // console.log(data.sprites)
        pintarPokemon(data);
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
};



const pintarPokemon = (data, data1) => {
    console.log(data1);
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    data.results.forEach((item) => {
        const clone = template.cloneNode(true);
        // clone.querySelector('.card-img').setAttribute("src", item.url.sprites.back_shiny);
        clone.querySelector('.text-center').textContent = item.name;
        fragment.appendChild(clone);
    });
    card.appendChild(fragment);
};
```

Debería verse algo así, pero con la respectiva imagen del pokemón: 
[image: Debería verse algo así, pero con la respectiva imagen del pokemón]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa bien los datos que vuelven de la API...haciendo una llamada rápida en postman puedo ver que ese endpoint te devuelve una lista de pokemon con dos datos: nombre (`item.name`) y un url del pokemon específico en el API (`item.url`)...  `item.url.sprites.back_shiny` no existe.

Para hacer lo que quieres, necesitas hacer una llamada al API por cada pokemon. Hice algo así hace poco, te dejo mi código:

```js
const colors = {
    fire: '#FDDFDF',
    grass: '#DEFDE0',
    electric: '#FCF7DE',
    ...
}

const fetchPokemons = async () => {
    for (let i=1; i <= pokemon_count; i++) {
        await getPokemon(i)
    }
}

const getPokemon = async (id) => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    createPokemonCard(data);
}

const createPokemonCard = (pokemon) => {
    const pokemonEl = document.createElement('div');
    pokemonEl.classList.add('pokemon');

    const name = pokemon.name[0].toUpperCase() + pokemon.name.slice(1);
    const id = pokemon.id.toString().padStart(3, '0');
    const types = pokemon.types.map(type => type.type.name);
    const type = main_types.find(type => types.indexOf(type) > -1);
    const color = colors[type];
    
    const pokemonInnerHTML = `
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png"" alt="${pokemon.name}">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <span class="number">#${id}</span>
        <h3 class="name">${name}</h3>
        <small class="type">Type: <span>${type}</span> </small>
    </div>
    `;

    pokemonEl.style.backgroundColor = color;
    pokemonEl.innerHTML = pokemonInnerHTML;
    poke_container.appendChild(pokemonEl);
}

fetchPokemons();
```

También lo puedes [ver en el repo](https://github.com/cangoman/50projects/tree/main/pokedex).